# Issue with Loading and Sorting Comments Using JavaScript (FETCH API) and Django

Tags: javascript, html, django, fetch-api

I'm working on a blog using Django and JavaScript, where users can submit and view comments on a post. I have implemented a functionality to sort these comments based on "newest", "Most liked", and "oldest" using a dropdown menu. Additionally, I've added a "Load more comments" button to paginate the comments.

When the page initially loads, the first ten comments are displayed, which is what i want. When a user clicks on the "load more comments" button, i want the next batch of ten comments to be displayed underneath, and so on until there is no more comment to be displayed, at which point the "Load more comments" button is hidden.

However, I'm facing some issues, and they are -

1. After clicking the "Load more comments" button, the initial set of comments is replaced by the next set of comments. Instead, I want the new comments to be appended below the existing ones.
2. The intended behaviour of the "Load more comments" button is only achieved **AFTER** changing the sorting option back and forth. What I mean is that after initially loading up the page, the "load more comments" button when clicked, replaces the 10 existing displayed comments with the next sets of ten comments. However, when you change the sorting option to something else (e.g., "oldest") and then switch back to "new," the "Load more comments" button starts working as intended by adding more comments without replacing the existing ones.

Of course, I believe this is a Javascript problem so below is the relevant part of my main.js -

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  // Define batch size and initial offset
  var batch_size = 10;
  var offset = 0; // Initial offset is 0
  var sortingOption = "new"; // Default sorting option
  var allComments = []; // Store all comments separately

  // Handle the change event of the sorting dropdown
  var sortDropdown = document.getElementById("sort");
  sortDropdown.addEventListener("change", function () {
    console.log("Dropdown change event fired");
    // Get the selected sorting option and post slug
    sortingOption = sortDropdown.value;
    var postSlug = sortDropdown.getAttribute("data-post-slug");

    // Reset the offset to 0 when sorting changes
    offset = 0;
    console.log("Selected Sorting Option:", sortingOption);
    console.log("Post Slug:", postSlug);

    // Make a Fetch API request to fetch the sorted comments
    fetchSortedComments(postSlug, sortingOption);
  });

  // Function to load more sorted comments
  function loadMoreSortedComments() {
    offset += batch_size; // Increment the offset
    var postSlug = sortDropdown.getAttribute("data-post-slug");
    fetchSortedComments(postSlug, sortingOption);
  }

  // Function to fetch and render sorted comments
  function fetchSortedComments(postSlug, sortingOption) {
    var sortingURL = `/sort_comments/${postSlug}/${sortingOption}/?offset=${offset}`;
    console.log("Sorting URL:", sortingURL); // Log the sorting URL
    fetch(sortingURL)
      .then(function (response) {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("Network response was not ok.");
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function (data) {
        console.log("Received data:", data); // Log the received data
        // Check if there are more comments to load
        var showLoadMore = data.show_load_more;
        var commentsSection = document.getElementById("comments-section");

        if (offset === 0) {
          // If offset is 0, it's the initial load, so store all comments
          allComments = data.comments;
        } else {
          // If offset is not 0, it's a load more operation, append to all comments
          allComments = allComments.concat(data.comments);
        }

        // Clear the existing comments
        commentsSection.innerHTML = "";

        // Render only the required slice of comments
        var commentsToRender = allComments.slice(0, offset + batch_size);
        commentsToRender.forEach(function (comment) {
          renderComment(comment);
        });

        // Show or hide the "Load more comments" button based on showLoadMore
        var loadMoreButton = document.getElementById("load-more-button");
        if (showLoadMore) {
          loadMoreButton.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          loadMoreButton.style.display = "none";
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
  }

  // Function to render a new comment on the page
  function renderComment(commentData) {
    var commentHtml = `
      <div class="comment">
        <div class="comment-header">
          <h3>${commentData.user}</h3>
          <span class="timestamp">${commentData.date_posted}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="comment-body">
          <p>${commentData.comment}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="comment-footer">
          <button class="comment-button"><i class="fa-solid fa-comment"></i>Reply</button>
          <button class="like-button"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i>Like</button>
          <button class="like-button"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>Delete</button>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="child-comments">
          <!-- Child comments go here (if any) -->
        </div>
      </div>`;

    var commentsSection = document.getElementById("comments-section");
    commentsSection.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", commentHtml);
  }

  // Add event listener for the "Load more comments" button
  var loadMoreButton = document.getElementById("load-more-button");
  if (loadMoreButton) {
    loadMoreButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
      loadMoreSortedComments();
    });
  }
});
```

I tried modifying the js code several times but i faced several duplication issues after clicking the "Load more comments" button, where the next batch of ten comments were duplicated with the initial 10 comments sandwiched in the middle. Some other modifications i made had the initial ten comments duplicated with the next batch of comments being displayed above them. The Javascript i provided above was the closest i could get to a working solution, but it only works after switching sorting options back and forth.

The following is the relevant part of my HTML in case it would help fix the problem -

```
<div class="card comment-card">
                    <div class="header">
                        <h2>Comments</h2>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="sort-comments">
                        <label for="sort">Sort by:</label>
                        <select id="sort" data-post-slug="{{ post.slug }}">
                          <option id="new-option" value="new">New</option>
                          <option id="liked-option" value="liked">Most liked</option>
                          <option id="old-option" value="old">Oldest</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div id="comment-container" class="comment-container" style="display: none;">
                      <form id="comment-form" method="post" action="{% url 'article:comment_submit' post.slug %}" data-slug="{{ post.slug }}">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <textarea id="comment-textarea"
                                  style="font-size: 16px; color: #333; background-color: #f2f2f2; border: 1px solid #ccc; 
                                  border-radius: 4px; padding: 8px; outline: none; text-align: left;" name="comment" rows="4" cols="50">
                        </textarea>
                        <button id="submit-comment" style="display: block;" type="submit">Submit</button>
                      </form>
                    </div>
    
                  <div id="comments-section">
                    {% for i, comment in comments %}
                      <div class="comment {% if i >= batch_size %}hidden{% endif %}">
                        <div class="comment-header">
                          <h3>{{ comment.user }}</h3>
                          <span class="timestamp">{{ comment.date_posted }}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="comment-body">
                          <p>{{ comment.comment }}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="comment-footer">
                          <button class="like-button"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i>Like</button>
                          <button class="like-button"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>Delete</button>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="child-comments">
                          <!-- Child comments go here (if any) -->
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </div>
                  
                  
                  {% if show_load_more %}
                    <!-- Load more comments button -->
                    <button id="load-more-button" data-offset="{{ batch_size }}" data-show-load-more="{{ show_all|yesno:"true,false" }}">Load more comments</button>
                  {% endif %}

                  </div>
        </div>
            
        </div>
```

The following is the relevant part of my views.py, I doubt the problem is in my views logic, but I include it still

```
def sort_comments(request, slug, sorting_option):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    offset = int(request.GET.get('offset', 0))  # Get the offset from the request's query string

    if sorting_option == 'new':
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post).order_by('-date_posted')
    elif sorting_option == 'liked':
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post).annotate(likes_count=Count('likes'))
        comments = comments.order_by('-likes_count', '-date_posted')
    elif sorting_option == 'old':
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post).order_by('date_posted')
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest("Invalid sorting option")

    batch_size = 10  # Set the number of comments to load per batch
    total_comments = comments.count()

    # Check if there are more comments to load
    if total_comments > batch_size + offset:
        show_load_more = True
        comments = comments[offset: offset + batch_size]
    else:
        show_load_more = False
        comments = comments[offset:]

    comment_list = []
    for comment in comments:
        comment_data = {
            'user': comment.user.username,
            'date_posted': comment.date_posted.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
            'comment': comment.comment,
        }
        comment_list.append(comment_data)

    return JsonResponse({
            'comments': comment_list,
            'show_load_more': show_load_more,
            'batch_size': batch_size,
            'total_comments': total_comments,
        })
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: It seems like the main issue is that when you load more comments, you are replacing the existing comments in the DOM instead of appending to them.